# Observer not capturing any value when using retrfofit with rx java

Tags: java, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java

On calling an api with retrofit, It is possible to obtain the data without rx java.

```
private fun <T> search(call: Call<T>?): T? {
        var d: T? = null
        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
                d = response.body()
                       println(response.body())
                       println(response) //working

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<T?>?, t: Throwable?) {
                println("failed")
                println(t!!.message)
                println(t.stackTrace)
                println(call)
            }
        }) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("")
        return d
    }
```

But if I switch to rx java

```
fun listingSearch(qrCode: Int) {
            val o =  AsRetroFitAPIClient.apiInterface.listingSearch(qrCode)
            search(o)
        }

private fun <T> search(call: rx.Observable<T>?): T? {
        var d: T? = null
        call!!.let {
            
            it.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(
            {value ->
                println("d")
                    println(value) //not working
            },
            { println("error")},
            {println("Completed")}
        ) }
        return d
    }
```

I am unable to obtain the value, The value is not getting printed as expected. Same class models were used when using without rx java. So I don't think there would be a problem with deserialization.

Other codes are below:

```
class AsRetroFitAPIClient {
    companion object {
        val apiInterface: AsApi = getClient().create(AsApi::class.java)

        private fun getClient(): Retrofit {
            val gson = RetrofitConfiguration.getGsonInstance()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(As.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(Gson()))
     .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                .build()
        }
    }
}

interface AsApi {
    @GET(AsConstants.LISTING_SEARCH + "{qrCode}")
    @Headers(
        "apiKey:${As.API_KEY}",
        "${RetrofitConstants.CONTENT_TYPE}:${RetrofitConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON}"
    )
    fun listingSearch(@Path("qrCode") qrCode: Int): Observable<Person>?
}
```

Comment: Is `"d"` getting printed? Neither version of your function is capable of returning the value of the call, only printing it. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Comment: @Tenfour04 No, It's not getting printed.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Any idea on why "d" is not getting printed? I couldn't understand.

Comment: I don’t see the problem, but I don’t have much experience with RXJava so I might be missing some detail. If this is a new project and you don’t have to use it, I would recommend using Kotlin coroutines instead anyway. It has reactive Flows but also has suspend functions, so retrieving single items like this can be done more simply.